# Read a file in background to update Qjsonvalue

Tags: c++, qt

I need to update the content of a field on my `QWidget` via a JSON file (updated in real time). I've read about functions `readLine()` and `readAll()` of `QFile`, but when I try a loop like :

```
while(true):
 jsfile.readLine()
 creation of objects, update of values, display etc ...
```

I lost the focus on my window. But I want to keep the control of the application with my buttons and obviously to watch the evolution of the JSON values.

I have thought that Qt manages itself the events and keeps the focus on the current window, but like I've said, it's not the case.

Is there a good solution (multi threads maybe) to use my window while the application reads the file (with new informations in real time)?

(With the constraint "real time" I can't read the whole file every time and I've no choice about the format of this file)

### Update

I tried the thread method.
So, I choose to create my thread instance into the main (with my main window) and connect here. But, when I run the program, I've this error :

> no matching member function for call to 'connect'

```
Reader reader;
QObject::connect(controler, SIGNAL(ready()),
                 reader, SLOT(received()));
```

According to this error, I've thought that the reason was main don't inherits of Object, and so, I've move the connection ans the creation of thread instance into my main window.

```
Reader reader;
QObject::connect(reader, SIGNAL(newobject(QJsonObject)),
                 this, SLOT(displayJSON(QJsonObject)));
```

With this one, I've the same error while I've already connect lot of widget into this class without any error.
What can be the problem ?

### Update 2

I've a solution when I give as argument my main window (controler) in reader's constructor and connect into this one but, if possible, I would an explanation for the previous problem.
The current problem that I have is that signals are emit well but slots are executed after the end the application (so after the end of the thread's execution and not during)
This isn't really the subject of this topic so we can close this one.

Comment: You problem is more about losing focus ? Set the necessary flags to decide who stays on top: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum
      ------    http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html

note: You also may want to use the thread solution below. you need both;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `QThread` (Qt documentation: [QThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html)) class to create a thread, which will read your file. The main thread will execute your GUI application and it will be available during file reading.
You can find a simple example in documentation for creating your thread:

```
class WorkerThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
    void run() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
        QString result;
        /* ... here is the expensive or blocking operation ... */
        emit resultReady(result);
    }
signals:
    void resultReady(const QString &s);
};

void MyObject::startWorkInAThread()
{
    WorkerThread *workerThread = new WorkerThread(this);
    connect(workerThread, &WorkerThread::resultReady, this, &MyObject::handleResults);
    connect(workerThread, &WorkerThread::finished, workerThread, &QObject::deleteLater);
    workerThread->start();
}
```

You can modify this example for your purpose. For example, `WorkerThread` for your task may be something like this:

```
class WorkerThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
    void run() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
        while(!stopFlag)
        {
            // read JSON file to QByteArray. Use QFile and QTextStream
            // use QJsonDocument to read JSON content
            // find what is new in JSON
            emit signalSomethingNew(/*parameters*/);
            QThread::currentThread()->msleep(/*timeout*/);
        }
    }
signals:
    void signalSomethingNew(/*parameters*/);
};
```

At the end you must implement slot on your `QWidget` for `signalSomethingNew(/*parameters*/)` and make connection:

```
connect(yourThread, &WorkingThread::signalSomethingNew, youWidget, &YouWidget::yourSlot);
```

For working with JSON data: [QJsonDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting your question as "my application is unresponsive whilst doing work" rather than "my focus jumped to another window" - please comment if you meant something different.

You have a choice of options:

1. Create and run a background `QThread` to do the work.  Have it emit signals (connected to your widgets using `Qt::QueuedConnection` - the default) when it has results to display.

   This is a good solution when the worker has a lot of computation to do, or needs all the input to be read before it can start.  It works very well when the target system has processors available with no other work to do.
2. Use a `QSocketNotifier` to signal your GUI thread when some of the input becomes available (note that the name is misleading - it actually works on all kinds of file descriptor, not just sockets).

   This is appropriate when the algorithm is simple and incremental - i.e. if a small chunk of input can be read and processed quickly.
3. Incorporate periodic calls to `processEvents()` in your algorithm:

   ```
   auto *const dispatcher = QThread::currentThread()->eventDispatcher;
   while (line = json.readLine()) {
       doSomethingWith(line);
       if (dispatcher)
           dispatcher->processEvents();
   }
   ```

   This won't work unless you can modify the algorithm like this - if the loop is in somebody else's (closed) code, then you'll need one of the other solutions.